# How do I monitor daily API transaction usage for the Alchemy API service on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, alchemyapi

As I use the Alchemy API service on Bluemix, I see the `daily-transaction-limit-exceeded` message. How can I monitor my transaction usage to determine when I am approaching the limit?

Answer (score 2):

Each API call typically equals many transactions. In the JSON response, you should see a transaction count returned for every API response that you receive from the server. However, you can determine the number of daily transactions that remain using the following query:
`curl -i http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/info/GetAPIKeyInfo?apikey=<api_key>`
Replace the `<api_key>` variable with your own API key. 
In the XML that is returned, you will receive a count of your daily usage plus the transaction limit.

Comment: is there any api call for watson conversation service as well?